# XY-pic: how to get symmetric curved arrows with entries different in length?

Tags: math-mode, xy-pic

I am using XY-pic to draw a simple graph with a double curved arrow (a simple version of exercise 5 in the xyguide). It appears that when the entries are different in length, the curved arrows get asymmetric. The following sample shows the issue: in the first row, the curved arrows are symmetric (because the entries have the same length); in the second row, the curved arrows are asymmetric.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{%
X\ar@/^/@{->}[rr]&&X\ar@/^/@{->}[ll]\\
XXXXX\ar@/^/@{->}[rr]&&X\ar@/^/@{->}[ll]
}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to render the curved arrows symmetric ?

Answer (score 2):

\phantom could be a fast fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{%
{X}\ar@/^/@{->}[rr]&&{X}\ar@/^/@{->}[ll]\\
{XXXXX}\ar@/^/@{->}[rr]&&{X\phantom{XXXX}}\ar@/^/@{->}[ll]
}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see it doesn't center.

Comment: Just leaving my answer as a starting idea because I don't see other answers yet. I will possibly delete it later.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, but now the row is unbalanced what can be an issue if the row is put in an equation environment, if it belongs to a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Not an Xy-pic answer, but a `tikz-cd` one, which shows it's rather easy to cope with the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge]
  X \arrow[r,bend left=12] & X \arrow[l,bend left=12]
  \\
  XXXXX
  \arrow[
    r,
    bend left=12,
    start anchor={[yshift=.5ex]east},
    end anchor={[yshift=.5ex]west},
  ]
  &
  X
  \arrow[
    l,
    bend left=12,
    start anchor={[yshift=-.5ex]west},
    end anchor={[yshift=-.5ex]east},
  ]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
\xymatrix{%
X\ar@/^/@{->}@<.5ex>[]+R;[rr]+L&&X\ar@/^/@{->}@<.5ex>[]+L;[ll]+R \\
XXXXX\ar@/^/@{->}@<.5ex>[]+R;[rr]+L&&X\ar@/^/@{->}@<.5ex>[]+L;[ll]+R
}
```

The key is to anchor each of the anchors at the right (`[]+R;`) or left (`[]+L;`) of the source node and the destination node (`[rr]+L` or `[ll]+R`).  Then to stop the two arrows from hitting exactly the same point, offset them a little (`@<.5ex>`).